# How to set Kafka acorss Multi DC

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer-consumer

Scenario: Currently, we have a Primary cluster, and we have Producer and consumer, which are working as expected. We have to implement a secondary Kafka DR cluster in another data center. I have a couple of ideas, but not sure how to proceed with?

Question: How to automate the producer switch over from Primary cluster to the secondary cluster if the Primary cluster/Broker goes down?

Any sample code will be helpful.

Comment: You wouldn't do this at the client level. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#georeplication

Comment: Okay, so are you saying we cannot automate it across 2 different clusters? And it has to be done manually if the primary cluster or producer goes down?

Comment: The producer on its own doesn't know how to recover when the primary comes back

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Load Balancer in front of your producer. The Load Balancer can switch to the secondary cluster if the brokers in primary arent available.

You can also implement the failover without a load balancer.

As a next step you have to configure in your code an exception handling which indicates a reconnect by yourself. So the producer are then still able to ingest.

Consumers can subscribe to super topics (several topics). This can be done with a regular expression.

For the HA Scenario you need 2 Kafka Clusters and Mirrormaker 2.0.

The Failover happens on client side Producer / Consumer.

To your question:
If you have 3 brokers and 2 ISR are configured, a maximum of 1 broker can fail. If 2 brokers fail, the high availability is no longer guaranteed. This means that you can build an exception handling which intercepts the error not enough replicas available and on this basis carries out a reconnect.

If you use the scenario with the load balancer, make sure that the load balancer is configured in the passtrough-. In this way, the amount of code can be reduced.